# php output buffering functions make the page load even slower

Tags: php, caching

I have a products search page that loads data from several sources. For speed optimization, I had put ob_start() on top of the page and ob_end_flush() at the bottom so that all the output is buffered and then printed. But this makes the page load even slow. It adds around 0.3seconds to the actual page load time.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect this to speed things up in the first place?!

Output buffering *stops* content from being sent to the client. It keeps everything back until you release it with `ob_end_flush`. If you didn't buffer, content would be sent to the client immediately as soon as you start outputting it. Of course output buffering will delay sending of the content by definition.

Comment: But I read on some forums that if the client browser is slow, then it would delay the receiving of data and apache will have to open the connection until all the data is received, so sending data atonce may speed up the overall connection. Is that wrong? I appreciate your kind reply. Thank you.

Comment: Makes little sense to me. Think about it: without buffering PHP will hand data to Apache immediately, and Apache can start sending it to the client as fast as it can. With buffering PHP stores all the data in memory first (uses more resources too) while Apache is doing nothing; then suddenly PHP dumps everything on Apache which then starts to send data to the client. There's obviously a delay where Apache and the client aren't doing anything while PHP crams its memory full of data.

Comment: I guess you are right, and that might be the reason. Thank you.